# Performance Difference Using Update Operation on a Mutable Map in Scala with a Large Size Data

Tags: performance, scala, collections, scala-collections, processing-efficiency

I would like to know if an update operation on a mutable map is better in performance than reassignment.

Lets assume I have the following Map

```
val m=Map(1 -> Set("apple", "banana"),
          2 -> Set("banana", "cabbage"),
          3 -> Set("cabbage", "dumplings"))
```

which I would like to reverse into this map:

```
 Map("apple" -> Set(1),
     "banana" -> Set(1, 2),
     "cabbage" -> Set(2, 3),
     "dumplings" -> Set(3))
```

The code to do so is:

```
def reverse(m:Map[Int,Set[String]])={
  var rm = Map[String,Set[Int]]()
  m.keySet foreach { k=>
       m(k) foreach { e =>
         rm = rm + (e -> (rm.getOrElse(e, Set()) + k))
       }
  }
  rm
}
```

Would it be more efficient to use the update operator on a map if it is very large in size?

The code using the update on map is as follows:

```
def reverse(m:Map[Int,Set[String]])={
  var rm = scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,Set[Int]]()
  m.keySet foreach { k=>
      m(k) foreach { e =>
         rm.update(e,(rm.getOrElse(e, Set()) + k))                                                        
      }
  }
  rm
}
```

Comment: This collections [performance doc](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics) might be of interest.

Comment: Thank you for the important reference. I did not know about it before. I had a quick look and the case for Map collection that I am asking about is not mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran some tests using [Rex Kerr's Thyme utility](https://github.com/Ichoran/thyme).

First I created some test data.

```
val rndm = new util.Random
val dna = Seq('A','C','G','T')
val m = (1 to 4000).map(_ -> Set(rndm.shuffle(dna).mkString
                                ,rndm.shuffle(dna).mkString)).toMap
```

Then I timed some runs with both the `immutable.Map` and `mutable.Map` versions. Here's an example result:

```
Time:    2.417 ms   95% CI 2.337 ms - 2.498 ms   (n=19)  // immutable
Time:    1.618 ms   95% CI 1.579 ms - 1.657 ms   (n=19)  // mutable
Time     2.278 ms   95% CI 2.238 ms - 2.319 ms   (n=19)  // functional version
```

As you can see, using a mutable Map with `update()` has a significant performance advantage.

Just for fun I also compared these results with a more functional version of a Map reverse (or what I call a Map inverter). No `var` or any mutable type involved.

```
m.flatten{case(k, vs) => vs.map((_, k))}
 .groupBy(_._1)
 .mapValues(_.map(_._2).toSet)
```

This version consistently beat your immutable version but still doesn't come close to the mutable timings.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to do the test. The performance is around 33% improvement. Would it also be possible  to add the test results for the functional version - just to compare all. The Rex Kerr's Thyme utility seems interesting and I will check it for other tests.

Comment: @user-asterix, as request: `Time:  2.278 ms   95% CI 2.238 ms - 2.319 ms  (n=19)`

Comment: just added the functional version results beside other results

Answer (score 1):

The trade-of between mutable and immutable collections usually narrows down to this:

- immutable collections are safer to share and allows to use [structural sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure)
- mutable collections have better performance

Some time ago I did comparison of performance between mutable and immutable Maps in Scala and the difference was about 2 to 3 times in favor of mutable ones.

So, when performance is not critical I usually go with immutable collections for safety and readability.

For example, in your case functional "scala way" of performing this transformation would be something like this:

```
m.view
 .flatMap(x => x._2.map(_ -> x._1))  // flatten map to lazy view of String->Int pairs
 .groupBy(_._1)                      // group pairs by String part
 .mapValues(_.map(_._2).toSet)       // extract all Int parts into Set
```

Although I used lazy view to avoid creating intermediate collections, `groupBy` still internally creates mutable map (you may want to check it's sources, the logic is pretty similar to what you have wrote), which in turn gets converted to immutable `Map` which then gets discarded by `mapValues`.

---

Now, if you want to squeeze every bit of performance you want to use mutable collections and do as little updates of immutable collections as possible.

For your case is means having `Map` of mutable `Sets` as you intermediate buffer:

```
def transform(m:Map[Int, Set[String]]):Map[String, Set[Int]] = {
  val accum:Map[String, mutable.Set[Int]] = 
    m.valuesIterator.flatten.map(_ -> mutable.Set[Int]()).toMap

  for ((k, vals) <- m; v <- vals) {
    accum(v) += k
  }
  accum.mapValues(_.toSet)
}
```

Note, I'm not updating `accum` once it's created: I'm doing exactly one map lookup and one set update for each value, while in both your examples there was additional map update.

I believe this code is reasonably optimal performance wise. I didn't perform any tests myself, but I highly encourage you to do that on your real data and post results here.

Also, if you want to go even further, you might want to try mutable `BitSet` instead of `Set[Int]`. If ints in your data are fairly small it might yield some minor performance increase.

Comment: Your code is a side topic and interesting and I had hoped that someone will give me a clue on how to create and update an efficient map. As I understand it, instead of a mutable map you created an immutable map from the list of values then created a mutable Set for each key. Thanks for the code sample.

Answer (score 0):

Just using @Aivean method in a functional way:

```
def transform(mp :Map[Int, Set[String]]) = {
   val accum = mp.values.flatten
                 .toSet.map( (_-> scala.collection.mutable.Set[Int]())).toMap
   mp.map {case(k,vals) => vals.map( v => accum(v)+=k)}
   accum.mapValues(_.toSet)
}
```